# Is Casablanca totally safe?

Tags: safety, stopovers, morocco, casablanca

My daughter is going to have a flight with one day stopover in Casablanca. Are there places to be avoided in Casablanca for a single young woman? Which ones might they be?

Comment: I know the question was edited to meet the FAQ but now the text  makes Casablanca seem like a city full of criminality with a few safe places.

Comment: _Are there safe places in Casa?_ this should be _Are there dangerous places in Casa?_

Comment: @HaLaBi: I reedited the question. Is this better?

Comment: Just as a general comment .. I sometimes think that any question of the form "Is {$FavouriteCity} safe?" is a bit meaningless as you can get into trouble in any city in any part of the world - including the "safe" parts.  However lists of explicit locales/behaviors to avoid are more useful.

Comment: @Alex Whats gives you the impression that Casablanca is unsafe ?

Comment: Actually I don't think it's unsafe, I don't know much about Casablanca except movie with this name, but my wife thinks, she always worries when our daughter is going abroad. So it's good to get confirmation that it's safe.

Comment: I would not call that dangerous, but a single young woman in Casablanca needs to have a thick skin ...

Comment: Casablanca is the most european city of Morocco. It is much ado about nothing. Except for its mosque it is quite a boring city. If time schedule permits I would advise your daughter to try to go to El Jadida (1h) or Rabat. There are nice highways that connect both.

Comment: @Alex How old is your daughter ?

Comment: twenty five years old (wanted to write 25, but it doesn't allow to write short comments)

Comment: @Alex Thats fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Casablanca in general is safe and the police is visible almost in all areas which makes you even feel safer. Also Morocco is one of the favorite countries for tourists in north Africa (maybe the first one) and it did not get that position if it wasn't safe enough for tourists. Just stick to these simple rules:

1. Don't go out late at night, unless in populated areas like beaches, clubs, traditional shopping areas, .etc.
2. Don't go to side roads or alleys if you are walking.
3. Don't talk to any strangers that offer help. Usually a young attractive innocent looking lady with a man in a suit and they speak few languages and have some tourism brochures which might makes people trust them. These people will try to convince you to take their tourist tour but once you ride with them or go with them to the *office* you will be robbed somehow or other.

Other than that, enjoy the city and the food there. They have very delicious local dishes you must try some of them.

Comment: I think you meant to say countries not cities

Comment: I think the first favorite city for tourists in Morocco or even North Africa is definitely Marrakech.

Comment: @HaLaBi Welcome

Comment: I would note that rules 1 and 2 apply to any big city.